# Django: method of model from querying a different one

Tags: django

I have a model `CartItem` that has a ForeignKey to a `Product` model.

Because from `Product` model I get the `description`, `image`, etc.

However, I want to have a method called `sub_total` that returns and integer. I use this to calculate total to be paid for this `CartItem`.

This sub_total method query a different model `costo_de_los_productos` using some of the properties of `CartItem`. like: `self.product.category.name`, `self.product.name`, `self.size`, `self.quantity`.

> I need to return an Integer from sub_total method.

However, something is not right with me query, if I comment it and return `0` it works, but total is 0.

```
def sub_total(self):    
  product_price = costo_de_los_productos.objects.filter(category=self.product.category.name,    
  product = self.product.name,
  size=self.size,
  quantity=self.quantity).values_list("price", flat=True)
```

What could be wrong?

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TAMANIOS)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CANTIDADES)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files', blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    step_two_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return str(self.id) + " - " + str(self.size) + " por " + str(self.quantity)

    def sub_total(self):
        product_price = costo_de_los_productos.objects.filter(category = self.product.category.name,
                                         product = self.product.name,
                                         size=self.size,
                                         quantity=self.quantity).values_list("price", flat=True)
        # print(type(product_price))
        return product_price
```

costo_de_los_productos model:

```
class costo_de_los_productos(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TAMANIOS)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CANTIDADES)
```

product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def get_url(self):
            return reverse('shop:ProdDetail', args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True, null=True)
    video = EmbedVideoField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:allCat', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

Image of "costo_de_los_productos" from Admin Panel:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Cannot print anything after the product_price query.

```
def sub_total(self):
    print("Enters Subtotal")
    print(self.product.category.name)
    print(self.product.name)
    print(self.size)
    print(self.quantity)
    product_price = costo_de_los_productos.objects.filter(category=self.product.category.name,
                                                          product=self.product.name,
                                                          size=self.size,
                                                          quantity=self.quantity).values_list("price", flat=True)[0]

    print("Line after product_price query")
    print(type(product_price))

    return product_price
```

Hard coding the values doesn't return expected integer:

```
def sub_total(self):
    print("Enters Subtotal")
    print(self.product.category.name)
    print(self.product.name)
    print(self.size)
    print(self.quantity)
    product_price = costo_de_los_productos.objects.filter(category="Stickers",
                                                          product="Stickers transparentes",
                                                          size="5cm x 5cm",
                                                          quantity=300).values_list("price", flat=True)[0]

    print("Line after product_price query")
    print(type(product_price))

    return product_price
```

prints results:

```
Enters Subtotal
Stickers
Stickers transparentes
5cm x 5cm
300
```

Comment: `sub_total` returns a Queryset, not a numerical value. To get the value of the first (and hopefully only) record, append `[0]` to the queryset definition.

Comment: I need to return an integer. put `.values_list("price", flat=True)[0]` at the end but result is the same

Comment: The result is not the same; even if it looks the same in the rendered template. If you uncomment the line with `type(...)`, you will see the difference. Open a Django shell (or a debugger) and check whether the queryset returns what you expect it to return.

Comment: @EndreBoth please, see update 1. Cannot print anything after the product_price query. Don't know why, I'd like to see the type of product_price

Comment: `Enters Subtotal` is  printed? and What is `costo_de_los_productos` ?

Comment: Then you must be getting an error in between. Do you have a try/except in the call chain that eats the error? Go to the shell and debug the queryset. You are filtering on four values; it might be that the values are not what you expect, or that the table doesn't contain what you expect, or even that the filter fields are wrong - you haven't shown the most relevant model `costo_de_los_productos`.

Comment: @EndreBoth I've added the model for `costo_de_los_productos`. I think the error maybe is because of the ForeignKeys on this model?

Comment: Yeah, It was the ForeignKeys. I've solve this. Post and answer if you will.

Comment: Congratulations! One tip: In the cost table, you should save a foreign key to the product table so you can query on product id + quantity, not lots of separate characteristics. This avoids duplication are reduces the potential for error.

Comment: @EndreBoth I do have a ForeignKey for the Product table in cost table. Could you be more precise?

Comment: Then why do you filter on category, product string and size instead of just product id? For more specifics, post the costo_de_los_productos model in the question.